# ViewStyle is not assignable to type StyleProp<ViewStyle>

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint, react-props

i am new to react-native and typescript so might be missing or making some silly mistake that's giving this error mentioned below. I'm creating a component which uses some other library where the "InnerComponent" lives and i am just importing it. I need to pass value from OuterComponent prop which is named as "myCustomContainer" to the InnerComponent prop which is named as "containerStyle" so i specified the same type of prop(StyleProp) as it's expecting in the InnerComponent but getting the following error.

```
Type 'import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").StyleProp<import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle>' 
    is not assignable to type 'import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").StyleProp<import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle>'.
  Type 'ViewStyle' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'.
    Type 'import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle' is not assignable to type 'import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle'.
      Types of property 'backgroundColor' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | typeof import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").OpaqueColorValue | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | typeof import("c:/myApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").OpaqueColorValue | undefined'.
          Type 'unique symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | unique symbol | undefined'.ts(2322)
             InnerComponent.d.ts(12, 5): The expected type comes from property 'containerStyle' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<InnerComponent> & Pick<Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "myCustomText" | ... 12 more ... | "someOtherContainerStyle"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'
```

Here is the code for the component i created and typed definition file(d.ts) of the imported component.

**My Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleProp, ViewStyle } from "react-native";
import { NavigationInjectedProps, withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import { InnerComponent } from "ComponentsLibrary";
import { myStyles as styles } from "../styles";

interface IProps {
  myText?: string;
  myCustomContainerStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}

type Props = IProps & NavigationInjectedProps;

export const MyOuterComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const {
    myText,
    myCustomContainerStyle
  } = props;
  return (
    <View>
        <InnerComponent
          customText={myText}
          containerStyle={myCustomContainerStyle}
          onChangeText={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
        />   
    </View>
  );
};
```

**InnerComponent.d.ts file for the component i am using**

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { StyleProp, ViewStyle } from "react-native";
/**
 * Component Props
 */
declare type Props = {
    containerStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
    someOtherContainerStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
    customText?: string;
    onChangeText: (customText: string) => void;
};
/**
 * Component State
 */
declare type State = {
    isTextMode: boolean;
    customText: string;
};
export declare class InnerComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
    static defaultProps: {
        onChange: undefined;
    };
    constructor(props: Props);
    someFunction: () => void;
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props): void;
    render(): JSX.Element;
    private onCancel;
}
export default InnerComponent;
```

Comment: Did you try to put here `myCustomContainer?: ViewStyle` instead of `myCustomContainer?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>` ?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error.  I'm seeing two errors https://tsplay.dev/oN9XMw - `onChangeText` gets a `string` text, not an event and `Props` has `myCustomContainer` not `myCustomContainerStyle`.  Fixing those is easy but I still don't see your error.

Comment: @dianaqqq Yes i did try(myCustomContainer?: ViewStyle) and getting the following error
 Type 'ViewStyle | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'.
     Type 'ViewStyle' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'.

Comment: @LindaPaiste i am still getting the error when i try what i mentioned in my post, i think (myCustomContainer/myCustomContainerStyle) could be a typo,